# Android WebView XMLHttpRequest Keepalive

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, android-webview, keep-alive

when making XMLHttpRequests in an Android WebView, no keepalive connections are used as it seems.

My desktop browsers all use keepalive when the requests are frequently made (eg. XMLHttpRequests triggered in a page's onload event are queued to the page's loading request connection).

Does anybody know what the requirements for a keepalive connection are (timeouts, headers..) ?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a HTTPUrlConnection http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

and set the Keep-Alive like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
```

This gives you a persistent URL connection.  Then you would use input and output streams to read & write your data to and from the server.

Comment: But this is implemented in the Android Java API. To use it, I would have to make a JavaScript wrapper for the WebView browser, not an easy thing.